Actual Python version in conda environment when running in Google Colab?
I run notebooks in Google Colab and there I install miniconda and create an appropriate environment for the application. It is good to be able to read out what Python version you actually have in the environment.
For example:
Calling platform.python_version() gives 3.10.12
Calling !Python --version gives 3.12.2
Calling !conda list python gives also 3.12.2
Seems to me that platform.python_version() refers to some other Python installation that I am not aware of. Likely in this example what !conda list gives is the relevant information for the local environment, right?
And what is this other Python installation really?

You should be using current best practices in Jupyter everywhere since Google Colab added support for the magic commands. I know they did at least for %pip. Anyway, try %pip list and %conda list. Those insure the command runs in the environment where the kernel of the notebook is running. Sometimes !pip or !conda runs off in a shell instance that doesn't match the environment where the active kernel is running, and so the magic variations were added in 2019 to eliminate that issue that can arise with using an exclamation point in conjunciton with pip or conda.  However,

 Google Colab is a different beast (despite a lot of people talking as if they are using Jupyter Notebooks) and so it really wasn't an issue there as they insured the exclamation point worked with pip. However, I know they finally added support for %pip finally making it consistent and I suspect they added %conda at that time, too, perhaps?? Again, it is a different beast then try Jupyter that has had these magic versions since 2019.

Thank you. Tested %pip list, and give expected information, but does not give the Python version in the notebook. It is simply not there. About %conda list, I get the ValueError that "...The python kerne does not appear to be a conda environment...". Not sure how to interpret that. Python is used in the notebook and works fine.

My approach/wish is to use identical notebooks and a general python setup script that works both in Windows and Linux and both in a local Jupyter notebook and in a remote Colab notebook.  So far it works quite fine, actually. But my setup_info() function that list key package versions etc, need to be fixed for telling the notebook Python version. Seems platform.python_version() should work everywhere...

For using MyBinder.org service (see my comments below Johnny's post) in parallel with your local stuff, you can make a binder directory where you put configuration files that MyBinder will use preferentially. In other words if there is a directory binder or .binder, MyBinder will use the configuration files in it and ignore those in root. That way those in root can still be used by your other situations, such as local use.

Yes, the Colab notebooks have a short list of commands to setup for Colab and allocate the right Github place. Then a general setup is done that is the same script for both Colab and local installation and both provide conda environment. I will into the idea of binder, sure!

So, notebooks are run using python kernels. And the kernel could be different from the default kernel in your bash/zsh or CommandPrompt terminal.
When you run this snippet you get python version that is used inside the Jupyter Notebook (Notebook kernel).
platform.python_version()

In comparison when you run the code below you get python env that is used in your bash/zsh/CommandPrompt terminal.
!Python --version gives 3.12.2
!conda list python gives also 3.12.2

Most likely this means that your 3.12.2 environment doesn't have a jupyter lab installed and thus command jupyter points to some other environment.
Also as a solution I would recommend to create new python kernel in the Jupyter Notebook and in the kernel path specify python path that you'd like to use during coding.

Thank you for your answer. Key is that I work both on local machines as well as using remote Google Colab virtual machines. My confusion is around Colab, I think. When I in Colab have installed miniconda and created the environment I want to work in, then I think !conda list give the actual packages and versions are available in the notebook. Therefore I thought that the Python version I find here by !conda list python actually is the notebook environment Python. But you mean it is not, right? Can you elaborate a bit more here?

Ok, I guess I missed the part about Google Colab. Anyway you get it right, in your case python version in the notebook is 3.10 and is different from python that you installed as a main system Python. Unfortunately it is very hard to change Python version in Colab Notebooks. For example read this thread where a Colab developer answers that they don't support changing Python versions: https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/4212 . However there are several very sophisticated workarounds that you may google and try to follow...

Personally won't recommend any of this workarounds for the following reason. You most probably use Google Colab to get access to GPUs. Google Colab by default gives you best configurations for their GPUs instances. Changing Python version may trigger errors in cuda_libs, then in tensorflow versions and then in smth else. Thus, my advice is to use as it is and downgrade your code to the Python version supported on the Colab.

Actually I use Google Colab mainly for demo notebooks around simulation of bioprocesses using the general purpose Modelica software compiled to FMUs. Thus, I do not make use of GPU etc so far. But a may need in the future. So I will consider your warnings and check the link you provided. Thanks!

The Jupyter community offers the MyBinder.org service for such uses of Jupyter. That gets you away from relying on a big company that is offering free compute to entice you for your business, and that may send that to The Google Graveyard at any moment leaving you in the lurch as you've become reliant on their system that isn't true Jupyter. Go to the 'Sample Binder Repositories' page here and click on the first 'launch binder' badge you see at the top under 'Python environment with a requirements.txt'. ...

 (The link to the repo that is the source of the configuration settings and content is to the right of it.) You'll get a temporary session with no login needed with the installed packages specified by requirements.txt already installed so that you can just do 'Run All' to run index.ipynb.  This example doesn't launch the notebook itself directly but you can set that. Example: click here (The repo that is the source for ...

 that is here). That launch URL just points the MyBinder.org service at the repo and specifies what to launch into. I almost forgot, importantly, you can use conda easily with MyBinder. It comes as part of it and you can use an environment.yml with it. Example repo is here. That was what the content at the 'Sample Binder Repositories' page I linked to above referenced further down the page under the heading 'Conda environment with environment.yml'.
